# Return 404 page for bad PHP variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I'm sure this must be easy but I just can't get my head around it.

I currently have a custom 404 page referenced in .htaccess; lets call it 404.php.

I also have a page (say 'test.php') which for simplicities sake looks like the following:

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET["id"];
  if ($id == 1) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
  } else {
    echo $id;
  }
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is; if variable 'id' = 1 (test.php?id=1) display the custom 404 page, else continue.

Currently status code 404 is returned in the header, but nothing displays.

My first question is; how do i get the 404 page to return?

Secondly; is this the correct way to return a 404 error for bad variables or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: To do it this way, you would need to include your 404.php file after the header line. `include_once "404.php"; die();`    Assuming Apache won't do this for you since the requested file does indeed exist, you need to create your own 404 response

Comment: Maybe this comment helps http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php#92305

Comment: An HTTP error doesn't automatically produce an error page. You have to provide one yourself.